# Parse logs in fluentd

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, docker, kibana, fluentd

I have local server running in docker container which is set to use fluentd as a log driver.
I have docker compose file which runs fluentd, nginx, elasticsearch and kibana in their own containers.
So fluentd takes logs from my server, passes it to the elasticsearch and is displayed on Kibana.

My question is, how to parse my logs in fluentd (elasticsearch or kibana if not possible in fluentd) to make new tags, so I can sort them and have easier navigation.

This is current log displayed in Kibana. Now I want this log string to be 'broken' into new tags. In this case:

```
2017/01/04 13:26:56.574909 UTC (Example deployment.web) [INFO] [GET] /api/device/ 200 10.562379ms
```

to

```
date: 2017/01/04
time: 13:26:56.574909 UTC
message: (Example deployment.web)
logType: [INFO]
other: [GET] /api/device/ 200 10.562379ms
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:

  fluentd:
    image: fluent/fluentd:latest
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/etc:/fluentd/etc
    command: /fluentd/etc/start.sh
    networks:
      - lognet

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - lognet

  kibana:
    image: kibana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200
    networks:
      - lognet

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8084:80"
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
    networks:
      - lognet

    networks:
      lognet:
        driver: bridge
```

my fluent.conf file, no parsing included, just simple forward

```
<source>
  type forward
</source>

<match *.*>
  type elasticsearch
  host elasticsearch
  logstash_format true
  flush_interval 10s
</match>
```

my try with regexp, here i try to parse logType out

```
<source>
  @type forward
</source>

<match *.*>
  type stdout 
</match>

<filter docker.**>
  @type parser  
  format /(?<logType>\[([^\)]+)\])/ 
  key_name log
  reserve_data false
</filter>
```

I tried other configurations but none resulted in parsing my logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone having similar issue i found a solution that works for me.

In fluent.conf file new *filter* tags are added. For instance, if I want to make new field called *severity* the first step is to record it with regex.

Example is ***[DEBU]***.

```
<filter *.*>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    severity ${record["log"].scan(/\[([^\)]+)\]/).last} 
  </record>
</filter>
```

And is afterwards deleted from original message:

```
<filter *.*>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    log ${record["log"].gsub(/\[([^\)]+)\]/, '')}   
  </record>
</filter>
```

The main part is:

```
severity ${record["log"].scan(/\[([^\)]+)\]/).last}
```

Where severity is name of the new field, record["log"] is original log string where string via regex is found and appended to the new field.

```
log ${record["log"].gsub(/\[([^\)]+)\]/, '')}
```

This command modifies field *log* where regex is substitued by empty string -  deleted.

NOTE: Order is important since we first have to append to the new field and then delete string from the original log message (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

First, tag your sources using `tag`. Second, in the match section include your tag key:

`include_tag_key true
 tag_key fluentd_key`

This works for me. The logs would be categorized by `fluentd_key`.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your answer.                                                   `<source>
  @type forward
  tag fluentd_key
</source>

<match *.*>
  @type elasticsearch
  host elasticsearch
  logstash_format true
  flush_interval 10s
  include_tag_key true
  tag_key fluentd_key
</match>`                                                                                                      I still cannot use custom format for my logs.

Answer (score 0):

we can use *record_transformer* option. like in below config:

```
      <filter kubernetes.**>
        @type record_transformer
        enable_ruby true
        <record>
          container_name ${record["kubernetes"]["container_name"]}
          namespace ${record["kubernetes"]["namespace_name"]}
          pod ${record["kubernetes"]["pod_name"]}
          host ${record["kubernetes"]["host"]}
        </record>
      </filter>
```

by this we can have container_name, namespace, pod and host as labels/tags. which we then can use further. below is the one of the sample use case.

```
      <match **>
        @type elasticsearch
        host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
        port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
        logstash_format true
        logstash_prefix ${namespace}_${container_name}
        <buffer tag, container_name, namespace>
          @type file
          path /var/log/${container_name}/app.log
        </buffer>
      </match>
```